# How to print json array data in a format

Tags: php, arrays, json

Let me explain what i want.
I have a two table name : grocery_product and grocery_attribute:
grocery_product fields are

```
   id
   pname
   categoryid
   subcatid
```

grocery_attribute fields are

```
    id
    product_id
    price
    discount
```

**PHP CODE :**
This is my code for API

```
    case "product_lists":
    $query = "select grocery_product.id as pid,grocery_product.pname,grocery_product.categoryid,grocery_product.subcatid,grocery_attribute.id as atribid,   grocery_attribute.product_id,grocery_attribute.price,grocery_attribute.discount,from grocery_product 
    right join grocery_attribute on grocery_attribute.product_id = grocery_product.id order by pid asc" ;  
    $result =  $link->query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);   
    $FetchArray = array();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows; 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $newData['id'] = $row['pid']; // PID as product ID
            $newData['pname'] = $row['pname'];
            $newData['categoryid'] = $row['categoryid'];
            $newData['subcatid'] = $row['subcatid'];  
            $newData['attrib_id'] = $row['atribid'];
            $newData['product_id'] = $row['product_id'];
            $newData['price'] = $row['price'];
            $newData['discount'] = $row['discount'];
            array_push($FetchArray,$newData);
        }

          $grocerryArray=array();
          foreach($FetchArray as $detail){

            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['id']=$detail['id'];
            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['pname']=$detail['pname'];
            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['categoryid']=$detail['categoryid'];
            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['subcatid']=$detail['subcatid'];
                                        // Get all grocerry_attribute data where grocery_attribute.product_id = grocery_product.id
                                        $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['details'][]=array(
                                            'attrib_id'=>$detail['attrib_id'], // attrib_id is grocery_attribute_id
                                            'product_id'=>$detail['product_id'],
                                            'price'=>$detail['price'],
                                            'discount'=>$detail['discount']
                                        );
            }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('Status'=>'Success', 'data'=>$grocerryArray, 'message'=>'You have successfully retrieved data'));break;
```

Current Output is

```
   {
"Status":"Success",
"data":{
        "1":
        {   
            "id":"1",
            "pname":"Royal Moong Dal Moong Dal",
            "categoryid":"4",
            "subcatid":"3",
                "details":[
                            {"attrib_id":"1","product_id":"1","price":"500","discount":"15"},
                            {"attrib_id":"2","product_id":"1","price":"800","discount":"10"},
                            {"attrib_id":"3","product_id":"1","price":"1100","discount":"20"}
                        ]
        },

        "2":
            {
                "id":"2",
                "pname":"Royal Toor Dal/Arhar Dal / Tuver Dal",
                "categoryid":"4",
                "subcatid":"3",
                    "details":[
                            {"attrib_id":"4","product_id":"2","price":"500","discount":"10"},
                            {"attrib_id":"5","product_id":"2","price":"50","discount":"10"}
                        ]
            }
    },
    "message":"You have successfully retrieved data"
     }
```

What I am looking for

```
[
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "pname":"Royal Moong Dal Moong Dal",
            "categoryid":"4",
            "subcatid":"3",
            "details":[
                    {"attrib_id":"1","product_id":"1","price":"500","discount":"15"},
                    {"attrib_id":"2","product_id":"1","price":"800","discount":"10"},
                    {"attrib_id":"3","product_id":"1","price":"1100","discount":"20"}
                ]
        }

        {
        "id":"2",
        "pname":"Royal Toor Dal\/Arhar Dal\/Tuver Dal",
        "categoryid":"4",
        "subcatid":"3",
            "details":[
                    {"attrib_id":"4","product_id":"2","price":"500","discount":"10"},
                    {"attrib_id":"5","product_id":"2","price":"50","discount":"10"}
                ]
        }


        ],
        "message":"You have successfully retrieved data"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace with below code . array_values that will be reset index of array.

```
case "product_lists":
    $query = "select grocery_product.id as pid,grocery_product.pname,grocery_product.categoryid,grocery_product.subcatid,grocery_attribute.id as atribid,   grocery_attribute.product_id,grocery_attribute.price,grocery_attribute.discount,from grocery_product 
    right join grocery_attribute on grocery_attribute.product_id = grocery_product.id order by pid asc" ;  
    $result =  $link->query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);   
    $FetchArray = array();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows; 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $newData['id'] = $row['pid']; // PID as product ID
            $newData['pname'] = $row['pname'];
            $newData['categoryid'] = $row['categoryid'];
            $newData['subcatid'] = $row['subcatid'];  
            $newData['attrib_id'] = $row['atribid'];
            $newData['product_id'] = $row['product_id'];
            $newData['price'] = $row['price'];
            $newData['discount'] = $row['discount'];
            array_push($FetchArray,$newData);
        }

          $grocerryArray=array();
          foreach($FetchArray as $detail){

            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['id']=$detail['id'];
            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['pname']=$detail['pname'];
            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['categoryid']=$detail['categoryid'];
            $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['subcatid']=$detail['subcatid'];
                                        // Get all grocerry_attribute data where grocery_attribute.product_id = grocery_product.id
                                        $grocerryArray[$detail['id']]['details'][]=array(
                                            'attrib_id'=>$detail['attrib_id'], // attrib_id is grocery_attribute_id
                                            'product_id'=>$detail['product_id'],
                                            'price'=>$detail['price'],
                                            'discount'=>$detail['discount']
                                        );
            }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('Status'=>'Success', 'data'=>array_values($grocerryArray), 'message'=>'You have successfully retrieved data'));break;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is remove your keys from your result array.
try PHP array_values(), ex

echo json_encode(array('Status'=>'Success', 'data'=>array_values($grocerryArray), 'message'=>'You have successfully retrieved data'));break;

Comment: Replace only this line?? it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Comment: You are welcome. And sorry for copy-paste error to make => becomes =.